# sha-512 vs sha-3?

Tags: cryptography, hash

Does the new SHA-3 Keccak hashing algorithm offer any benefits from SHA-512?

"Even worse, none of the SHA-3 candidates is significantly better. When SHA-3 is announced, I'm going to recommend that, unless the improvements are critical to their application, people stick with the tried and true SHA-512. At least for a while."

Source: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/09/25/sha_3_hash_contest/

Comment: At least higher security margin and no length extensions.

Comment: "higher security margin" - And that means?

Comment: that it's probably harder to break.

Comment: with an emphasis on "probably" - no one actually knows which one is harder to break...

Comment: @nealmcb's answer on the linked question details the reasons for Keccak very well.

Comment: The duplicate question is not a duplicate. Perhaps the answer there is useful, but I don't think closure is appropriate unless it's the same _question_.

Answer (score 4):

Since SHA-512 has stood the test of time, the argument Schneier is making is essentially:

- There is nothing wrong with SHA-512, it has not proven insecure (even though it looked like it may be 7 years ago)
- All the new systems proposed as SHA-3 are at best only very slightly smaller or faster than SHA-512, and that speed up doesn't justify the risk of pushing out something new and relatively untested (wrt a decade or so of SHA-512)

New systems are a pretty big deal, since they often have implications for the next round of hardware, recommendations that inform audits and compliance testing, etc. - so there needs to be a pretty high bar to clear between major versions of a major standard.